# Selecting more than one elements where one of the elements is $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to select an element along with `$(this)`?

I know selecting more than one element is possible in jQuery by separating them with a comma(,).

For e.g. we can select two ids, say "element1" and "element2" as:

```
$("#element1,#element2")
```

However, I'm not able to select more than one element if **one of them is $(this)**, i.e. I can't select $(this) and $("#element") simultaneously in a single selection. How do I achieve this?

Comment: What is it that you want to do to the selected items ?

Comment: Create a css class for the styles and add it to this via `classList.add()` one less jquery operation to run

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to insert more elements

```
$("#element1, #element2").add(this)
```

or the other way around

```
$(this).add("#element1, #element2")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/)

```
$("#element1,#element2").add(this)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you select any element in jQuery you create array. Even if you select one element:

```
var id = jQuery("#my-id");
console.log(id); // [element]
```

so You can do something like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("a").on("click", function(){
        var allElements = jQuery("div");
        allElements.push(this);
        console.log(allElements)
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndw24abz/)